# How can I execute a subset of tests in OpenLiberty dev mode

Tags: testing, open-liberty, liberty-maven-plugin

In order to execute the whole test suite you only have to press `enter` key in `dev` mode.

But how to execute one only test or a subset of the whole test suite?

Comment: You can file an issue at https://github.com/OpenLiberty/ci.maven/issues to suggest this as an enhancement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since dev mode dynamically loads pom.xml changes, one approach would be to dynamically edit the pom.xml configuration and then hit `<Enter>`  e.g.:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>

            <configuration>
                <test>BonusPayoutIT#testForceFailure</test>
            </configuration>

        </plugin>
```

Comment: This way runs all the tests as unit tests and then re-runs the tests configured in pom.xml as integration tests.

Comment: I'd think you could extend this idea to excluding unit tests via `maven-surefire-plugin` config.

Comment: I tried <excludes> and it doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: Are you expecting to use the 'failsafe' plugin to configure unit tests?   You probably need to use the 'surefire' plugin for UTs and 'failsafe' for ITs.   Maybe you could show your pom or a snippet?

Comment: I got it, knowing the differences within surefire and failsafe and using <includes> inside <configuration> works great. Thanks.